# Create and add a new variable with the pipe operator = Create a Plot out of it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create and add a new variable called "XY" by multiplying the capital income of several countries by 1000 and then divide it by its population = gdp*1000/pop. Afterwards I want to make a plot with selecting the years and countries (Here I want to select certain countries from the data, e.g. Turkey, France, Germany and the timeframe should be 1996 and later meaning 1997, 1998 etc.), where I want to have the x-axis with years and the y-axis with capital income. I want to have every country in a different colour. How can I put this in a R-code. My start so far is like this:

```
  > # two pipes
  > gapminder %>%
  +     select(Germany, Italy, France) %>%
  +     select(population >= 1996)

  plot(eu_macro$germany, eu_macro$turkey, eu_macro$france, gdp_capita$medv, main = "GDP 
  development", xlab = "Year", ylab = "gdp_capita")
```

Sorry, I am very new to R and Coding in general and just hope to get an understanding for it for Finance classes.

Comment: Perhaps `select(population >= 1996)` should really be `filter(population >= 1996)`? `select` is for selecting *columns*, `filter` is for filtering in/out *rows*.

Comment: From there, that pipe is ephemeral, it is stored nowhere and instantly lost. If you want to use it, you can either save it to a variable or pipe it directly to a plotting function (assuming you place the `.` in the right argument and are using magrittr's `%>%` and not base R's `|>` pipe operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ary you looking for such a solution?

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
gapminder %>%
    mutate(XY = gdpPercap*1000/pop) %>% 
    filter(country=="Germany" | 
           country=="Turkey"|
           country=="France") %>%
    filter(year >= 1996) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=factor(year), y=XY, fill=country)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    ggtitle("GDP development") +
    xlab("Year") + ylab("gdp_capita")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you actually that helps and gave me thoughts about a further step. Is this also possible without the gapminder function? And how can I change colours, years etc in this?

Comment: 1. The dataset is in this package. So if you want to use it you have to call the library. 2. Change the colors by adding 'scale_fill_manual' <https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html>